# Slider that overflows parent and page - CSS only

Tags: css, slider, position, overflow

Is is possible to create a slider that would "overflow" parent elements and body?

The idea would be to have content of section inside a container.
Slider would also be a part of that section but the slides would overflow parent element and body.
Vertical scroll would be wide as container but you could see slides outside of the container.

```css
h2{
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:460px;
  border: 2px solid #ef34ed
}

.slider{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  jusify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.slide + .slide {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.slide{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Some title</h2>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
        <p>Name</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
        <p>Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
        <p>Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <p>
    Magna phaedrum electram pro an. Te nec delectus temporibus, omittantur ullamcorper ne pri. Pri ad affert urbanitas, laboramus eloquentiam pri ad. Purto summo interpretaris eam et, brute dolore ut eam, illud dolore putent et vim. Ei sed aliquip iudicabit, te fabulas menandri sed.

    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
h2{
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:460px;
  border: 2px solid #ef34ed;
  overflow: visible;
}

.slider{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding:0 calc(calc(100vw - 460px)*0.5);
  margin:0 calc(calc(100vw - 460px)*-0.5);
}

.slide + .slide {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.slide{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Some title</h2>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
        <p>Name</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
        <p>Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
        <p>Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="person" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <p>
    Magna phaedrum electram pro an. Te nec delectus temporibus, omittantur ullamcorper ne pri. Pri ad affert urbanitas, laboramus eloquentiam pri ad. Purto summo interpretaris eam et, brute dolore ut eam, illud dolore putent et vim. Ei sed aliquip iudicabit, te fabulas menandri sed.

    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: That you for the answer. This is not quite what I was looking for but it helped me to create my own solution. First one would be using ::-webkit-scrollbar (https://jsfiddle.net/codeANDcode/kbjh8n97/). I was not really happy with this solution because there is no support for FireFox (https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar). The second solution was using Swiper slider (https://jsfiddle.net/codeANDcode/uzokgm65/). Swiper uses translate and has it's own scrollbar which can be used inside container. I also have support for all major browsers. Thank you for your help and general idea.

Comment: @CodeAndCode Glad I was of help to you